# Check multiple columns for null in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Table A:

```
Id  Name  DateCreated  DateModified
-----------------------------------
1    A     2013-1-12    2013-1-15
2    B     NULL         2013-2-1
3    C     NULL          NULL
```

I have to migrate this table's data to another table in which `DateCreated` is a not nullable column, and the conditions are if `DateCreated` is null use `DateModified` and if both are null use current date.

I can't use

```
ISNull(DateCreated,DateModified)
```

because both can be null.

How do I do it? The table has around 10000 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested `Isnull`

```
Isnull(DateCreated,isnull(DateModified, getdate()))
```

Or use a `CASE`

```
case when DateCreated is null and DateModified is null then getdate()
     when DateCreated is null then DateModified 
     else DateCreated end
```

Comment: coalesce does all this stuff: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: colesce has some precedence problem, thats what I knew, but in this case since the data types are same both will work. Marking this as correct answer, because it was answered first. Both are actually correct, and so an upvote for both.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `COALESCE(DateCreated, DateModified, GETDATE())`

Answer (score -2):

is is simething like this you are looking for?

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);

if ($result) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    if ($row['DateCreated'] == 'NULL'){

        if ($row['DateModified'] == 'NULL'){

                $today = date("Y-m-d");
                $id = $row['id'];
                $query = sprintf("SET DateCreated = $today WHERE id = $id");

            } else {
                $newDate = $row['DateModified'];
                $id = $row['id'];
                $query = sprintf("SET DateCreated = $newDate WHERE id = $id");}
        }
  }

}
else {
  echo mysql_error();
}
```